# QTabWidget's QTabBar is a few pixels to the right. How to align it at the same horizontal position as QTabWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qwidget, qtwidgets

I have sub-classed QTabWidget and have two tabs in there. I have overridden ::resizeEvent() of QTabWidget to change the width of tabs, so they can take half of the width of QTabWidget. In TAB1 (left tab), I have a horizontal splitter (QSplitter), which divides the tab in two equal parts, in each of them displaying a different QWidget. It all works fine, except that QTabBar's top left X offset is a few pixel to the right. I think QTabBar itself is shifter a few pixels to the right. How do I fix this?

Here's the code:

```
void WelcomeTabWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
    tabBar()->setMinimumWidth(event->size().width());
    tabBar()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    _splitter->setSizes({event->size().width() / 2, event->size().width() / 2});
    //The line below does not have any effect, so might as well remove it.
    QTabWidget::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Here's what it visually looks like (the offset is marked at two places in red):

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening due to style sheets that were set for the overall application:

```
QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    left: 5px; /* move to the right by 5px */
}
```

So, it's fine:)